# Create HTML file from React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I need to convert particular react components into html file so i can send those html to server for generate pdf file.

Is there any libraries available? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `document.getElementById('myHtml').outerHTML()`

Answer (score 1):

I entered this question looking for the answer to the following question:
"How to generate a **HTML file** from a React component?".

But the author actually wants to generate a **PDF file** from a React Component.

Fast forward to this date, here is what you wanted:

### [React-pdf: React renderer for creating PDF files on the browser, mobile and server.](https://react-pdf.org/)

[Github Link](https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You must use ref in react, this is react way to do it :

```
class Com extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.createRef = this.createRef.bind(this);
    }
    createRef(elem){
        //use elem and get the html element.
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div ref={(elem) => this.createRef(elem)} >
                <span>hey</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: okay while doing this scripts and styles also automatically apply? or we have do something for that?

Comment: what do u mean ? you can also use @justinas solution. did u get the picture ? after react rendered the html. u can do what ever u want

Answer (score 0):

You can render react components in Node on the server using Server Side Rendering.

If you can pass props to the server side, and render the component there then on the server side you should be able to grab the HTML generated and pass that to something which can create a PDF.

What are you using on the server? are you after a one off render or do you expect to be able to render the same components with different props over time?

A quick google search turned up these libraries:

https://github.com/lang-ai/react-pdfs
https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf
https://www.npmjs.com/package/generate-pdf
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf

And this article:

https://medium.com/@tomsp/server-side-render-pdfs-with-blaze-and-phantomjs-in-meteor-34b8b63522c

Comment: I'm using python in server side. yes render same components with diff props over time.